# How to instantiate a component from it's class in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to instantiate a class inside render:

```
import myFirstComponentfrom './components/myFirstComponentfrom'
import mySecondComponent'./components/mySecondComponent'

  additionalComponents= [
    {component:myFirstComponent},
    {component:mySecondComponent}
  ]
...

render(){
  return (
    <View>
      {additonalComponents[0].component}
      {additonalComponents[1].component}
    </View>
}
```

unfortunately, it's not working... any idea how this can be done?

Thanks,

Comment: Please elaborate your question a little bit more. _not working_ is not enough information and please try to give a little bit more complete example of your code so people can debug easier.

Comment: The instantiation of additonalComponents[0].component fails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, using:

```
render(){
  return (
    <View>
      {React.createElement(this.additionalComponents[0].component, {})}
      {React.createElement(this.additionalComponents[0].component, {})}
    </View>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React Native does not treat as classes any object that does not start with Uppercase. myFirstComponent should be MyFirstComponent.

Also, the imports are wrong, but I am assuming that is type otherwise that wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {MyFirstComponent} from './components/myFirstComponentfrom';
import {MySecondComponent} from './components/mySecondComponent';

  const additionalComponents = [
    {component:myFirstComponent},
    {component:mySecondComponent}
  ]
...

render(){
  return (
    <View>
      {additonalComponents[0].component}
      {additonalComponents[1].component}
    </View>
}
```

Your component name should be First Letter Capital, and your import isn't look right.
Maybe this will help.